# Getting LibCurl to work on iOs...

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, curl, libcurl

Does anyone have any experience getting LibCurl working on iPhone OS? Any Tutorials or sample code available for getting understand all thing related to cURL for iOS Development.

Comment: Here's a link that might help: http://creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42

Comment: I found this https://github.com/sinofool/build-libcurl-ios among others.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a sample application and static libaries at:
http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html

i wasn't able to build a working xcode project to compile my own framework, so i wrote a bash script

```
CurlVersion="7.29.0"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="4.3"
otherBuildFlags="--with-darwinssl"

rm -rf results 
rm -rf Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/$CurlVersion
mkdir -p results/iOS
mkdir -p results/Sim

make clean
export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
export CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk"
export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk"
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-dependency-tracking --host="armv7-apple-darwin" --host="armv7s-apple-darwin" $otherBuildFlags
make -j `sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max`
cp lib/.libs/* results/iOS/

make clean
export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2"
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk"
export CPPFLAGS="-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=${IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%%.*}0000"
export LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk"
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --host="i386-apple-darwin" $otherBuildFlags
make -j `sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max`
cp lib/.libs/* results/Sim/

lipo -create results/iOS/libcurl.a results/Sim/libcurl.a -output results/libcurl.a

mkdir -p Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/$CurlVersion/Headers
mkdir -p Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/$CurlVersion/Resources

cp include/curl/*.h Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/$CurlVersion/Headers/
cp results/libcurl.a Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/$CurlVersion/

cd Products/libcurl.framework/Versions/
ln -fs $CurlVersion Current

cd ..

ln -fs Versions/Current/libcurl.a libcurl 

ln -fs Versions/Current/Headers .
ln -fs Versions/Current/Resources .
```